# Query one row with max value in one column in Slick

Tags: scala, slick, slick-3.0

It seems to me like a simple problem, but I still try to find a good solution.
I am using Slick 3.0.
I want to query the row of a table, which has the highest value in one column. But I don't want to only have the highest value (this is simple), I want to have the whole row.
I tried some things, like query first the max and then filter with this max value, but nothing compiled or looked appropiate.
I would expect to be there a method like that:

```
table.maxBy(_.columnName)
```

But I didn't found a method like that.
So what's the favorite way to do something like that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way to do it is to use this query:

```
table.sortBy(_.columnName).take(1).result
```

Unfortunately it produces SQL that is not optimized (but correct). [Issue](https://github.com/slick/slick/issues/1160) is reported and fixed, it'll be released in 3.1.0.

Comment: For `maxBy`, this should be `_.columnName.desc`